# Mysql Indexing not possible for which datatype

Tags: mysql

For which data type indexing not possible ?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for everything that fits in a table

The question you should ask is for which datatypes is it unwise to use indexing. Big text's that you don't search through I wouldn't add an index. Large bit filled fields I wouldn't use an index on either...

Normally you would use indexing on integers, tinyints, bigints, varchars, etc... small datatypes that don't take a lot of processing power to compare with eachother.